# Can I solve the error TF253022 (You must update your client with the Forward Compatibility Update) on a build server without installing VS2008?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

This is a build server running Cruise control version 1.6.7981.1.

I am basically running a test by pointing an existing (seldom used CC build) to our new TFS 2010 server.

This fails with the error listed in the title.

I am clearly missing a step or two...

I assume that CC must be using TF.exe for source control access?  And it must be using the 2008 version.  And the update adjusts this somehow?  Or performs some other update?  Maybe I can do whatever the update is doing myself?  Or configure CC to use the 2010 version of TF.exe?

Maybe it's just a question of installing the 2010 client tools (and hopefully this is backwards compaitble).  I am trying that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about CC but the forwards compatibility update is for Team Explorer, which contains a subset of the VS IDE. There are 2 versions one for [2005](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=22215e4c-af6f-4e2f-96df-20e94d762689&displaylang=en) and one for [2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cf13ea45-d17b-4edc-8e6c-6c5b208ec54d). I'd check in "Add remove programs" to see which version is installed. You'll need to make sure that either VS 2005 SP1 or VS 2008 SP1 is installed (depending on which version of Team Explorer is installed) before installing the update.

Comment: I was really hoping that was not the case.  I don't really want VS installed on my build server, although I gather from my reading that many teams do this.  If I could figure out what the update was doing I was hoping I could get avoid it.

Comment: I'm know what you mean, however if tf.exe is installed I would have thought you already have Team Explorer installed, which as I said, already includes a subset of VS. The service pack won't install any extra bits of VS, just patch the ones that are already installed. and the Forward Compatability update then patches the SP1 install. If you check add / remove programs on the server and you see "Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx Team Explorer ENU" then you already have visual studio installed, but not the full blown IDE, just enough to connect to TFS.